# Print Preview Issue in Safari

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS:

```
@media print {
  SELECT {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 35px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
}
```

If I see the print preview it works fine. But the select arrow is missing. Is it possible to fix it? Please guide me.

Comment: When exactly is  the arrow missing? In the preview or in the print itself? You do have `-webkit-appearance: none;` in there, the whole purpose of which is exactly not have a `select` element look like one.

Comment: try to show in jsfiddle.net to solve easily and fast